# Tick marks inside with image function with R

Tags: r, image, plot

I am trying to have the tick marks inside my plot with R image function.

I red a fits image and I represented it into a PDF file using the "image" function in R. The result is fine, but the tick marks are outside the plot and I want them pointing inside.

image(1:dim(imn2223J)[1], 1:dim(imn2223J)[2], imn2223J, zlim=c(-8,15), asp=1, col=rev(rainbow(100)), xlab= "X - Arcsec", ylab="Y - Arcsec",cex.lab=2.5, cex.axis=2.5)

I have succeeded to have other tick marks inside, but the original ones from image are still there pointing outside. Someone encountered this prb ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `tcl = 0.5` in your `image()` call?

Answer (score 0):

Most base graphics functions like `image()` accept graphical parameters in the `...` arguments.  Those are documented in `?par`.  The one you want is `tcl`; positive values point into the plot.  The default is `tcl = -0.5`, half a line of text pointing outwards.  For the same length pointing inwards, use `tcl = 0.5`.